# American HTTP Proxy For testing Application

Tags: macos, proxy

I have an App which should display an Information dialog if a user comes from the US. I am located in Europe and want to test this functionality.

Does anyone know a Proxy which allows me "appear like a US citizen"?

**Update:** I tried out approx. 10 different proxies and they all time out when I open www.google.com in my browser.

I configured the proxy in the Preferences like this:

```
Network Settings -> Ethernet -> Advanced -> Proxies:
```

[image: Proxy Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googling for `free proxy list`](http://www.google.com/search?q=free+proxy+list) will produce heaps of results.

If you want to have a more reliable proxy, you can get an Amazon EC2 micro VM (or any other virtual root server) [for free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) for one year of usage. Then, logon to the machine, and install [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/), Apache with [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), or any other HTTP proxy server.

Comment: I tried using such a proxy but out of the 10 I tested none of them worked.

Comment: @Besi Yes, the quality of proxies tends not to be good since they're mostly offered by volunteers without access to high-bandwidth connections and/or good data centers. Setting up your own proxy as described should work fine though.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I could now partially test it with a German proxy. When I have time I might setup my own using your suggestion. Thanks